# When are both fractions integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of absolute values of all real numbers $x$, such that both of the fractions $\displaystyle \frac{x^2+4x−17}{x^2−6x−5}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1−x}{1+x}$ are integers, can be written as $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers. What is the value of $a+b$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac{2}{1+x}-1$$

and

$$\frac{x^2+4x-17}{x^2-6x-5} = \frac{10x-12}{x^2-6x-5}+1.$$

We need both of these to be integers. So $\frac{2}{1+x}$ must be an integer, and happens when, for example, $x=-3,-2,0,1$ (you also need to check rational values). You can plug these into the second fraction to test its integrality. Then take the sum of the appropriate values.

Comment: here x is a real number not an integer

Comment: @AgarwalShubham It is not hard to modify this approach to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\text{I}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{x^2+4x−17}{x^2−6x−5}=1+\frac{10x-12}{x^2-6x-5}=1+2\frac{5x-6}{(x-3)^2-14}$$

$$\text{II}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\frac{2}{1+x}-1$$

Look at II: the first fraction on the RHS must be an integer, so... The values you found with this substitute in I and do then some mathematics...

Comment: here x is a real number not an integer..
from II we can say that x is a rational number..

Comment: Yes @AgarwalShubham, I know: so what?

Comment: No @AgarwalShubham , you can say way more...

Comment: we know x is rational number, and from I we compare it to with integer (say c). Now form the quadratic and here discriminant is perfect square for x is rational.. but i am stuck after this..

Comment: thanx @DonAntonio I have solve the problem
as we find value of x from II which is (1-c)/(1+c) and put it on I.